# How to know when @ResponseBody ends

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, response

I have a method annotated with @ResponseBody that return xls file and works fine if is normla post request.

Now I need to show on the view a loading effect. So first show loading ajax popup, second I call method with ajax post but i don't know how to handle response on success to download or open the file and close the popup.

Can you recommend me another strategy?

Now the code is like this.

```
    //Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/generateXls", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void generateXls(@ModelAttribute Filter filter, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session,  HttpServletResponse response) 
                throws Exception 
    {
         /*Code for generate xls*/
    }


//View
//function called on form submit.
function callGenerateXls() {
    /* SHOW LOADING POPUP */
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "report/generateXls",
    data: $("#filter").serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
       /* HOW TO HANDLE RESULT ????? */
       /* HIDE LOADING POPUP */
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Once response is written on output stream return any String for example "success" and "failure" in case of any exception and then check in success method of AJAX call and close your popup window or show any message in case of some failure.

Comment: I can't return any String after write at outputstream beacause getOutputStream() just has been called (java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() ). My problem is how to handle result of controller annotated with @ResponseBody on view (success method on ajax post).